# How to reference 1 cell to right in an IF(COUNTIF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the formula I am currently working with:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Tasks!A:A,RC[1])>0,"Task","None")
```

I want 1 column to monitor the text of another column in another sheet of the worksheet.

So, look in Tasks's `column A` for text matching this sheet's 1 cell to the right of current cell, if it is found, populate word Task in current cell, otherwise, populate word None.

For example:

`Sheet1 column A` is blank but is going to contain the above formula in every cell. `Sheet1 column B` has various different text. If that text is found anywhere in the Tasks sheet `column A`, then populate the word Task, otherwise, populate the word None.

The formula was working when it was:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Tasks!A:A,B2)>0,"Task","None")
```

But then I realized I need it to be more dynamic.

I'm sure I am just missing a parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: The reason `=IF(COUNTIF(Tasks!A:A,RC[1])>0,"Task","None")` does not work is you are mixing `A1` and `R1C1` style addresses.  You can use either, but only one.  That said why is `=IF(COUNTIF(Tasks!A:A,B2)>0,"Task","None")` not dynamic enough?

Answer (score 1):

You want `=IF(COUNTIF(Tasks!A:A,OFFSET(A1,0,1))>0,"Task","None")`

Where A1 is whatever cell you're starting in on Sheet1 column A.